# Unable to construct Application instance

Tags: javafx

I am trying to launch in my public class an application defined in another class, earning the "Unable to construct Application instance"-Exception.The example (below) is quite minimalistic. What am I missing?---Clues would be very much appreciated.

This question is different from the question

[Unable to construct javafx.application.Application instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599423/unable-to-construct-javafx-application-application-instance)

as I would like to have the definition of an application and its launch in separate classes.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(OKButton.class, args);
    }
}

class OKButton extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button btn = new Button("OK");
        Scene scene = new Scene(btn, 200, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the same Exception thrown, but quite a different setting and question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that the constructor of your `OKButton` class is not accessible for JavaFX. You have to either put your `OKButton` class in a separate file or use it this way:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(OKButton.class, args);
    }

    public static class OKButton extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {
            Button btn = new Button("OK");
            Scene scene = new Scene(btn, 200, 250);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Halko. This is an option. However, I wanted to have my main-class small and tidy and therefore keep the OKButton-class somewhere else.

Comment: then put your OKButton-class in a OKButton.java file in the same directory

Comment: Same Exception, nothing changes.

Comment: did you add `public` before your class name? e.g. `public class OKButton extends Application {`?

Comment: Here we go.... Thank you, indeed.

Comment: you're welcome!