# JavaFX: Launch out of another class

Tags: java, javafx

I want to program after the Model View Controller Concept in my `JavaFX` application and so I coded the launch method into my view package in the GUI class. Here you can see my GUI Class:

```
public class GUIFalscherName extends Application {


// Komplexe Datentypen
  //*********************************//
  VBox elternteil;

  Label testLabel;
  //*********************************//

  public GUIFalscherName(String[] args) {
    GUIFalscherName.launch(args);
  }

  public void start(Stage buehne) throws Exception {
    buehne.setTitle("Test");
    this.elternteil = new VBox();
    this.testLabel = new Label();
    this.testLabel.setText("test");
    fuegeKomponenteDemParentHinzu(testLabel);

    Scene scene = new Scene(elternteil);
    buehne.setScene(scene);
    buehne.show();
  }

  public void fuegeKomponenteDemParentHinzu(Node komponente) {
    this.elternteil.getChildren().add(komponente);
  }
}
```

Here you can see my main class from where I want to call the constructor of the GUI class where the launch is to launch the GUI.

```
public class FalscherName {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUIFalscherName guiFalscherName = new GUIFalscherName(args);
  }
}
```

So my goal is to tear the main part apart from the GUI part and to not mix them, as the Model View Controller Concept says.

However, when I run my code I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class de.falschername.view.GUIFalscherName
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.falschername.view.GUIFalscherName.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$7(LauncherImpl.java:818)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to construct javafx.application.Application instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599423/unable-to-construct-javafx-application-application-instance).

Answer (score 0):

This is the main problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.falschername.view.GUIFalscherName.<init>()
```

Which is saying it can't find a *no-argument* constructor in the `GUIFalscherName` class. This is to be expected since you only have one constructor, and it's:

```java
public GUIFalscherName(String[] args) {
    GUIFalscherName.launch(args);
}
```

Which expects a single argument. The need for a no-argument constructor is documented by [`Application`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html):

> The `Application` subclass must be declared public and **must have a public no-argument constructor** *[emphasis added]*.

You placement of `GUIFalscherName.launch(...)` is also incorrect. When you launch a JavaFX application via `launch`, the JavaFX runtime will construct an instance of your application class for you (using reflection). Since you invoke `launch` in the constructor that means you're creating an instance which causes a *different* instance to be created, while the original instance is simply left to be garbage collected. If you want to launch JavaFX from a separate main class, one which doesn't inherit from `Application`, then you need to use [`Application#launch(Class,String...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String...)):

> Launch a standalone application. This method is typically called from the main method. It must not be called more than once or an exception will be thrown.
>
> The launch method does not return until the application has exited, either via a call to `Platform.exit()` or all of the application windows have been closed. The class specified by the `appClass` argument must be a public subclass of `Application` with a public no-argument constructor, in a package that is `exported` (or `open`) to at least the `javafx.graphics` module, or a `RuntimeException` will be thrown.

<sup>***Note:** The part dealing with exported/opened packages is related to modules which were added in Java 9. If you aren't developing in Java 9+, or otherwise not using modules, then that part is not relevant to you.*</sup>

For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;

public class FalscherName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(GUIFalscherName.class, args);
    }
}
```

And you need to remove the constructor you have defined in `GUIFalscherName`.

If you need access to the command line arguments, use [`Application#getParameters()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters()).

Answer (score -1):

Please see below java doc.

> Launch a standalone application. This method is typically called 
>   from the main method(). It must not be called more than once or an 
>   exception will be thrown.  This is equivalent to
>   launch(TheClass.class, args) where TheClass is the  immediately
>   enclosing class of the method that called launch. `It must  be a
>   subclass of Application or a RuntimeException will be thrown`.

When I try to call from other class then I get below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class FalcherName is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:254)
at FalcherName.main(FalcherName.java:5)
```

Comment: But what does this mean? What do I have to do now?